# MultiSelect List from UI to Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0

i am presently working on an API to create form data. however one of the fields is Multiselect with options.

MY model looks like this

```
public record createAdmissionDto
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public List<string> EducationLevels { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have **multiple education levels** such as **(Bsc, Phd, Pgd)** collected from the user. How can i get all of them into a list from my controller? Also i will need to check these selections after i receive them

[The kind of form the front end will be like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMQDK.jpg)

Comment: You've not really given much information here but I'd recommend using an Enum list instead of a string list.  I'm assuming that your education levels are chosen by you and not the end user.  So you'd end up with List<Education> EducationList, you'd then bind the EducationList to your selector as the DataSource and it will populate with the Enums.  This also means adding new levels is just adding another value to your Enum.

Comment: Can you update your question with what you have so far, if anything? Just a model doesn't give us much to go on. What does your service and frontend currently look like? Are you only looking to build out the controller in the API or something more?

Comment: try to set default constructor and make EducationLevels  = new List, now , user might provide list <int> or Dictionary<int,string> - you need to coordinate this too.. to set a custom validation - you can use custom DocumentAttribute validation on EducationLevels